# What permission level is need to view past versions of a document?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, versioning

If I have versioning enabled on a document library... can everyone view the past versions?

Or only the document owner or owners group?

Answer (score 1):

Read permissions allow users to view past version history of list items.  You can look at your permissions levels by going to Site Actions->Site Settings->Site Permissions, then click on Permissions Levels in the ribbon.  I would suggest getting familiar with these permissions and perhaps creating your own to do what you want.  Even Read permissions might give too much control to your basic user.

Answer (score 1):

Read permission grants a user "View Version" base permission by default.

If you have minor & major version turned on in a library, you can limit who can view the minor versions in the version history (readers, contributors, approvers) in List -> Settings -> Version Settings -> Draft Item Security.